# Retrieving Windows Password Hint from the registry

Tags: .net, windows, c#-4.0, regedit

I have been trying to extract the Windows login password hint for Windows 7 programmatically and I came to know it can be retrieved from the following location in the registry 
*HKLM\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\"userkey"\UserPasswordHint*
However, I am not able to figure out is there any way to find out `userkey` for the currently logged-on user programmatically?

Comment: Why do you need the password hint? The only use I can see for this hint is to present it to the user when asking for the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get the current user name, it's quite easy, using the same registry tree.

Take a look in `HKLM\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\Names\{username}`. The value of the entry would relate to the proper `userkey`.

Of course remember the hint may not exist.

**EDIT**

Ha! Nailed it!

As you said in a comment, it's not the values of the node that contain the proper value, it's the type of a default entry of that node. It's hard, if not impossible, to obtain with c#, as this types are not standard. I have troubles with this approach, so I changed it.

The hexadecimal value you call the `userkey` is, in fact, the last part of the user SID (this part is called RID). As far as I know, every Administrator has RID = 500, every Guest = 501, normal users starting with 1000 or 1001, can't remember right now.

And what is it in hexadecimal?

```
500 = 0x1f4
501 = 0x1f5
1000= 0x3e9
...
```

Looks familiar?

So what we need to do is to get this SID of a user, extract the interesting part, convert it to padded hexadecimal string and retrieve the value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SecurityIdentifier sid = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
    var rid = sid.ToString().Split('-').Last();
    var hexValue = int.Parse(rid).ToString("X").PadLeft(8, '0');
    RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\"+hexValue);
    try
    {
        var hint = key.GetValue("UserPasswordHint");
        //...
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not access value");
    }
}
```

**WATCH OUT!**

As far as I know you cannot access SAM database if you're not privileged enough. Running it as System user (e.g. with `psexec -s yourbinary.exe`) helps, but it changes the current user, and the program fails. So you need to work out on your own how to run it for an interesting user.

Comment: Thanks Piotr. I did see this registry. But, the registry contains zero-length binary value. However, I see that the type of the value is same as the user-key. But again, I was not able to extract and use this from code.

Comment: Well @Ishan, I must say it's a tough one. I can't easily retrieve this value, yet. I'll keep you posted.