# Set the Password Hint on Local Account using C#

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a Solution for setting the Password Hint once I change Password of a Local User.

This is the Code I am using to change the password, but find no solution to set the password hint:

```
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);

        user.SetPassword(password);
        user.Save();
```

I have even tried to use 'DirectoryEntry' to set both Password and Hint but ending up with an Exception and don't know what I can solve the Problem:

```
        DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
        DirectoryEntry grp = AD.Children.Find(userName, "user");
        if (grp != null)
        {
            grp.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "test" });
            grp.Invoke("Setinfo", new object[] { "a password hint" });
        }
        grp.CommitChanges();
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What's exception?

Comment: @xxbbcc "SetPassword" shows an UnauthorizedAccessException although I am Administrator and "Setinfo" shows an "TargetParameterCountException: parameter count mismatch"

Comment: `SetInfo` is called after calling `Put` with a property name and value two element array.

Comment: @NetMage I can't find a Put Method on DirectoryEntry. Did you perhaps mean InvokeSet?

Comment: See https://books.google.com/books?id=fbbcf-5L6FsC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=directoryentry+invoke+setinfo&source=bl&ots=-IVX7UnJVS&sig=EKacAdRfr73xordTaWR54hl_avo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE9NrH4ZvXAhUTxCYKHTYcB_YQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=directoryentry%20invoke%20setinfo&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `HKLM\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\<userkey>\UserPasswordHint` is stored in the SAM accessible under the Registry if you have sufficient permission - see this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603724/2557128

Comment: I granted Full Access to SAM in Registry and start my Application as Administrator. But I'm still not be able to write to this Registry Key :(

Comment: Full access to the account running the application?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and logged in with a user who is a member of Administrators. So the user must have write access to registry. Am I missing something?